# QuantLib SWIG Java: Undefined symbol sessionId()

Tags: java, c++, swig, sessionid, quantlib

I have successfully compiled QuantLib 1.12 on Ubuntu with --enable-sessions and --enable-thread-safe-observer-pattern flags. I also compiled java Swig bindings. When I try to run Bonds example in java, I get an undefined symbol error on sessionId().

```
java -cp ./QuantLib.jar:. -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib examples.Bond

java:symbol lookup error:/usr/local/lib/libQuantLibJNI.so:undefined 
symbol:_ZN8QuantLib9sessionIdEV
```

Any idea how to resolve this error? I saw some references to implementing sessionId() function externally and linking to QuantLib. I am not sure how to do that exactly. Can I add "mysessions.cpp" file under ql/ folder and build QuantLib as usual? The file mysessions.cpp will have following content:

```
#include <thread>
int QuantLib::sessionId(void)
{
     return std::this_thread::get_id().hash();
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, adding your file to the build will work; to do that, you'll have to add it to the list of files in `ql/Makefile.am` (you're on a Linux or Mac system, right?).  You might need `autoconf` and `automake` installed.  Also, you might have to run `./autogen.sh` to reinitialize the `configure` cache with your versions of the tools.

Comment: Adding a new file under ql/ folder requires changes to Makefile and make fails because Ubuntu16 has version 15 of automake and QL make requires 15.0.1 which is not available for apt-get install. So I chose to put mysession.cpp file under ql/patterns folder, so no change to makefile. I also changed sessionId to return unsigned long to match boost/thread. I still get undefined symbol error. 1. Do I need to #include singleton.hpp in my mysessions.cpp file since that is where I am providing the definition? 2. Do I need to change any of the swig .i files that came with the tarball? Thank you.

Comment: If you save it in `ql/patterns`, you need to add it to `ql/patterns/Makefile.am`.  There's no way around that.  Your `automake` should be ok; see my update to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Luigi. I was able to get it working. here are some important steps :
I was working with Oracle VirtualBox Ubuntu 16.04.3 hosted on Windows 10.

Create a mysessions.cpp file under ql/patterns folder as follows after including boost/lexical_cast.hpp and boost/thread.hpp

```
namespace QuantLib {
  unsigned long sessionId(){
    std::string threadId = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>
    (boost::this_thread::get_id());
    unsigned long threadNumber = 0;
    sscanf(threadId.c_str(), "%lx", &threadNumber);
    return threadNumber;
  }
}
```

In singleton.hpp, change the return parameter of sessionId() from Integer to unsigned long. You have to change in many places, also change the key of instances_ map from Integer to unsigned long in many places.

Add myssesions.cpp to ql/patterns/Makefile.am

```
cpp_files = \
      observable.cpp \
      mysessions.cpp
```

On Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, the automake version is 1.15 and needs to be upgraded to 1.15.1 as follows

```
sudo apt-get remove automake #remove 1.15
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/automake-1.15.1.tar.gz
tar xf automake*
cd automake-1.15.1
sh configure --prefix /usr/local
make install
```

When building QuantLib, in configure step, the command needs to be following

```
sudo ./configure --disable-static CXXFLAGS=-O3  
--enable-thread-safe-observer-pattern --enable-sessions
```